# WinRT XAML Toolkit Visualization error

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml-toolkit

I have a page where I want to put a chart using WinRT Xaml Toolkit Data Visualization Controls.

I have the following code:

```
   <Charting:Chart x:Name="PieChart" Width="400" Height="400">
        <Charting:Chart.Series>
            <Charting:PieSeries IndependentValuePath="X" DependentValuePath="Y"/>
        </Charting:Chart.Series>
    </Charting:Chart>
```

VS tells me, PieSeries is wrong: "A value of type 'PieSeries' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'Collection`1'".

Why is this an error?

Comment: The author of the toolkit basically says you need to work around it. https://winrtxamltoolkit.codeplex.com/workitem/810

Answer (score 0):

It's not fully tested, but it seems like this is what the sample does right now, could you do something similar?

```
<charting:Chart
    x:Name="PieChart"
    Title="Pie Chart"
    Margin="70,0">
    <charting:Chart.Series>
        <Series:PieSeries
            Title="Population"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
            IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Name}"
            DependentValueBinding="{Binding Value}"
            IsSelectionEnabled="True" />
    </charting:Chart.Series>
</charting:Chart>
```

Comment: What is the `charting` and the `Series` namespace? (I assume that charting is `WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting`.) I have already tried `WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting.Series`.

Comment: I think they're both the same namespace now. The separate XML namespaces are just an artifact of some earlier refactoring. I suspect your error is simply due to bug in the code and so you might be best off by referencing the source code for the library (you need DataVisualization + base WinRTXamlToolkit) and debug it to see what's going on.

Comment: If they are the same namespace, I still have the problem. But if I start a blank application, it works fine. But anyway, thank you.