# Windows phone application gui is not updating

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I am using WinRT xaml Toolkit to make one Pie Chart in Windows Phone Application but when i run this application i do not get the gui of PieChart. 
I also included WinRTXamlToolkit.dll and WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.dll as reference.

Here is the xaml coding :

```
<Page
    x:Class="App6.MainPage"
    xmlns:Charting="using:WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App6"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

        <Button x:Name="ButtonRefresh" Content="Refresh" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="100,57,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="ButtonRefresh_Click"/>

        <Charting:Chart x:Name="PieChart" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="100,100,0,0" Width="400" Height="400">
        <Charting:PieSeries Margin="0" IndependentValuePath="Name" DependentValuePath="Amount" IsSelectionEnabled="True"/>
        </Charting:Chart>


    </Grid>

</Page>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using WinRTXamlToolkit.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;

// The Blank Page item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=391641

namespace App6
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public class FinancialStuff
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public int Amount { get; set; }
        }

        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
        }

        void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            LoadChartContents();
        }

        private void LoadChartContents()
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            List<FinancialStuff> financialStuffList = new List<FinancialStuff>();
            financialStuffList.Add(new FinancialStuff() { Name = "MSFT", Amount = rand.Next(0, 200) });
            financialStuffList.Add(new FinancialStuff() { Name = "AAPL", Amount = rand.Next(0, 200) });
            financialStuffList.Add(new FinancialStuff() { Name = "GOOG", Amount = rand.Next(0, 200) });
            financialStuffList.Add(new FinancialStuff() { Name = "BBRY", Amount = rand.Next(0, 200) });

            (PieChart.Series[0] as PieSeries).ItemsSource = financialStuffList;

        }

        private void ButtonRefresh_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            LoadChartContents();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where are you running? what version of VSTS? do you see any errors in the output log?

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 12.0

Comment: Error : A value of type 'PieSeries' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'Collection`1'. c:\users\comsc\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\App6\App6\MainPage.xaml

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23226022/winrt-xaml-toolkit-visualization-error

Answer (score 0):

I think that error is present for quite sometime in that framework. Can you try this?

```
<Charting:Chart x:Name="PieChart" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="100,100,0,0" Width="400" Height="400">
    <charting:Chart.Series>
        <Series:PieSeries
            IndependentValuePath="Name"
            DependentValuePath="Amount"
            IsSelectionEnabled="True" />
    </charting:Chart.Series>
</Charting:Chart>
```